# SDK for Android Studio failed to install and I can't launch and virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

So, this is the message that came up after I was trying to download the system image of a device with Android API 27:

```
To install:
- Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-
27;google_apis_playstore;x86)
Preparing "Install Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision:1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-
img/google_apis_playstore/x86-27_r01.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Play Intel x86 Atom 
System Image: Cannot download 
'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/x86-
27_r01.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 1)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-
27;google_apis_playstore;x86)
```

I am a beginner in this and I really have no idea what to do.

Comment: Do you have poor internet connection? `Read time out`

Comment: Not that much, but even if, when I had a strong internet connection it didn't work.

Comment: Do you even need the Intel Atom System Image?

Comment: It says that a system image must be downloaded to make the virtual device

Comment: Yes, but the Atom Image is for special machines. You only need the regular Intel x86 image, not the "Google Play Intel Atom" one

Answer (score 4):

I got same issue, let try this
- File --> Invalidate Caches and Restart your Android Studio.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are behind a proxy, you need to configure that in Android Studio, I guess.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Go to Android Studio settings> Appearance and Behaviour > System settings > HTTP Proxy. Here you can fill in the proxy settings. If you do not know these values, you can simply connect to an open network and disable "Cisco AnyConnect Service" or any other similar service that your comany uses.

Comment: One very simple solution would be is to find an open network and make it work!! Hope that helps!